# Visual Studio 2017 can't find std::variant

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, c++17

I am using Visual Studio 2017 - 15.9.7 for C++ development, and it looks like I have the necessary modules installed.

[image: Installed VC++ modules]

But the code below gives the error - "namespace "std" has no member "variant""

`std::variant` is supported in C++17 and looks like it was introduced to [Visual Studio in 15.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2017)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
int main()
{
    std::variant<int, double, std::string> value;
}
```

It looks like someone asked the same thing before, but the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54047180/vs2017-returns-error-namespace-std-has-no-member-variant) appears to have been deleted.

Comment: Did you enable c++17 for your project?

Comment: Have you selected the compiler option that enables C++17?

Comment: The question you linked even says to check the compiler settings. If that's the issue then this is going to get deleted as well.

Comment: @john - woops, that's what it was...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can also go
`Project` > `Properties` > `C/C++` > `Language`

and set `C++ Language Standard` to `ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)`

make sure to be on `All Configurations` and `All Platforms`
[image]

Comment: Are there options to select `All Configurations` and `All Platforms`? Or, are you just saying make sure to set the c++ version the same for all projects manually?

Comment: @starriet I mean if you look at the very row, it says "Configuration: " and "Platform: ". Those should be set.

Comment: Oh, I think I'm kinda blind ;) Thanks! 
P.S. for newbies like me: @Tiib's answer also works the same way, but it uses commands and this answer uses the menu (this adds the command such as `/std:c++17`).

Answer (score 10):

Project → Properties → C/C++ → Command Line `/std:c++latest`

Then click <kbd>Apply</kbd> and <kbd>OK</kbd>.